# Add a persistent progress bar to launcher icon

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I'm trying to write a script (python) to add a progress bar to an launcher icon. When I execute my script the icon changes, then my script exits and it changes right back. How do I change the icon in such a way the it will stay after my script exits?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Unity, GObject

launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("gnome-terminal.desktop")
launcher.set_property("progress", 0.5)
launcher.set_property("progress_visible", True)
loop = GObject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Comment: you probably just want to change [`Icon` field in `gnome-terminal.desktop` file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)

Comment: Not what I want. I will be using another script to change it back latter on.

Comment: I see only two choices: a) your current script runs the whole user session b) you change Icon field (programmatically)